# Establish a simple mongohq connection

Tags: php, mongodb, mongohq

Is there a way to establish a connection to a cloud mongoDB (such as mongoHQ), with no drivers or third party apps, from a localhost server?

In other words, I want to host my php files locally, and connect to a mongoDB on the cloud.

I've been doing simple websites using php and MySQL as a hobbie for a few years, and I'm pretty decent at it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this one simple thing with Mongo.

Whenever I run a file that does:

```
$m = new Mongo('mongodb://username:password@staff.mongohq.com:XXXXX/database');
```

from a php file, I get a HTTP 500 error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. In advance I apologize if this isn't clear enough, this is my first post on SO. Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Do you have the proper MongoDB PHP Module installed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your PHP/apache error log to see what the HTTP 500 error is ?  Try adding to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Based on your code sample, I would check that you have the [Mongo module installed](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) as it will generally not be included by default.  Use `phpinfo()` and look for the **mongo** section.

If you want to use MongoHQ without installing a Mongo driver, you could also try their [REST API](http://support.mongohq.com/api) which apparently is still in beta phase.

Comment: Turns out I hadn't installed the mongo driver, as you and @Bobby had pointed out. (Thank you).

This link has a great walkthrough on how to do it:

[Installing MongoDB on MAMP 1.9.5 : David Golding][1]


  [1]: http://www.davidgolding.net/mongodb/installing-mongodb-on-mamp-1-9-5.html

Comment: The instructions there work fine for installing a precompiled Mongo PHP driver, but would note that this is currently an older driver version (1.0.11, versus the latest which is 1.2.10).  There's an alternative install guide if you want to [build and install the latest version under MAMP](http://m-schmidt.eu/2011/11/06/develop-mongodb-web-apps-with-mamp-under-mac-os-x/).